# trying to get data from databese in laravel but getting error .why?

Tags: laravel

//this is the create.blade.php. it saying undefined variable data.but when i send from controller.php.please suggest the error. ////this is the controller.php. here i am trying to send in data from database.

```
  <center>
    <form method="POST" action="{{url('/insert')}}">
    {!! csrf_field() !!}
      First name:<br>
      <input type="text" name="task_name" ><br>
      Last name:<br>
      <input type="text" name="task_detail" ><br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" value="save">
    </form>

    </center>

    <center>
    @foreach($data as $value)

    {{$value->task_name}}

    <br>

    {{$value->task_detail}}


    @endforeach

    </center>
```

//

```
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;


    use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
    use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use DB;

    class Controller extends BaseController
    {
        use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;


               public function insert( Request $req)

        {
                $name=$req->input('task_name');

                $detail=$req->input('task_detail');

                $data=array('task_name'=>$name,'task_detail'=>$detail);

                DB::table('tasks')->insert($data);
                echo "success";
                $this->show();
        }

        public function show()

        {

            $data = DB::table('tasks')->get();

             if (count($data>0))
              {
                  return view ('create',$data);
              }
             else

              {

               return view ('create');

              }
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you are passing the variable in the wrong way; use `compact()`. like so:

```
if (count($data>0))
              {
                  return view ('create',compact('data'));
              }
             else

              {

               return view ('create');

              }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to update your show function like:

```
public function show()

{

  $data = DB::table('tasks')->get();

  if (count($data) > 0)
  {
      return view ('create',compact('data'));
  }
  else

  {

   return view ('create');

  }
}
```

Hope this work for you!